# Hide <li> with dynamic data based on magento attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

We are using Magento for our eCommerce site. Our products have custom attributes on the backend that we use to display product specific information. Our products are displayed with jquery .accordion < li> statements

```
                <li>
                    <div class="handle">
                        <h3><?php echo $this->__('Tartans') ?></h3>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                <div class="panel loading">
                    <?php echo $this->__($_product->getData('usak_tartans')); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="handle">
                    <h3><?php echo $this->__('Tweeds') ?></h3>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel loading">
                    <?php echo $this->__($_product->getData('usak_tweeds')); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="handle">
                    <h3><?php echo $this->__('Measuring') ?></h3>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel loading">
                    <?php echo $this->__($_product->getData('usak_measuring')); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
```

What are looking to achieve is that if there is no data in the attributes on the backend, it will hide the < li> section for that product. I have tried several options I have found on the net, however most of them read the php echo and keep it active.

Thanks for any help
- Rob

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I hide the data list section if there is nothing in populated by the getdata section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about sth. like :

```
 <li <?php if($this->__($_product->getData('usak_tartans')) == ''){echo "style='display:none;'"; } ?> >
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, though I am playing around with the <?php if to see if I can use your example and make it function. When I put that into my site, it doesn't display anything, no matter what is in the 'usak_tartans' section on the backend.

Comment: **UPDATE** Strike that last comment; I used your snipit and modified the jquery .accordion, it works perfectly!   Thank you!